# activeX/OCX simple HTML editor

Tags: html, delphi, activex, ocx, html-editor

I am looking for a simple HTML editor.

This package should fulfill the following:

1. Generates old type of HTML with no CSS
2. Fully supports Right-To-Left and Hebrew fonts
3. Must be an ActiveX / OCX component

Most editors in the market that I found so far, generate sophisticated HTML

What can you recommend?

**EDITED**

I need it for a desktop application. I want the user to be able to edit text like in HTML editor (font styles, alignment) etc.

Comment: What do you need this for - are you planning to build HTML E-Mails?

Comment: Would a combination of a Richtext (RTF) editor control and a library which [exports](http://scroogedemo.appspot.com/sx) to HTML be acceptable?

Comment: No. I built a desktop applications, and I want the user to be able to insert text and edit it easily

Comment: @mjn it might be good but I have to check it. Can you recommend one?

Comment: Why do you want it as an ActiveX/OCX instead of native Delphi component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nBit HTML Editor ActiveX/OCX (Commercial)](http://nbit.net.au/vpages.aspx?ID=HTML%20Editor%20OCX) seems to fit your requirements, except that the website does not state explicit support for hebrew/Right-to-left, so let's assume it doesn't support those, unless you can download a demo and try it. I have not used it so I cannot say.

It supports but does not seem to require CSS.

Comment: k I will try it and let you know

Answer (score 2):

One option which works well in desktop applications would be using a Richtext control, like TRichEdit or [TRichView](http://trichview.com/) (commercial) for the editor.

RTF supports unicode and LTR and RTL (right-to-left) languages.

The generated RTF source can be exported to HTML, either with TRichView export functions or a converter library like my (commercial) [ScroogeXHTML](http://www.habarisoft.com/scroogexhtml_delphi.html) library.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it and get back to you

Comment: it will take me 1-2 days to check it

Comment: Hi! it won't help. since we are storing the HTML not the RTF. and also this editor creates <span> on almost every text. Is there a way to do it with out it?

Comment: Yes, ScroogeXHTML can be configured to use a default text style (font, color, size) and then it will create formatting elements only for text which uses non-default styles. This can even eliminate all span elements, for text which uses only one style.

Comment: The problem is that I need an HTML editor and not RTF converter. I need to save the HTML for future editing..

Comment: In this solution, only RTF would be the source, edited and stored and HTML is only an output document. Do I understant correctly you mean the users create the HTML text, and later it would have to be edited again but then in a way which can not be done in the original document using the RTF editor?

Comment: Good point. TRichEdit is natively RTF, and has somewhat imperfect HTML-in and HTML-out capability.  Nevertheless it is used commercially by lots of tools that are written in Delphi, and which do exactly what you are looking for, but which have to store RTF and simply output HTML, in order to be robust.

Answer (score 1):

TRichView can import the HTML into RTF, then export it as HTML. I use it for a chat program message composer and a group chat message viewer by sending HTML between clients. I'm not sure about the span tag.

Comment: I don't need a conversion tool. I need an editing tool. Can this component allow editing the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The `TWebBrowser` component used to allow editing; I haven't checked it lately but this is what I can find on Google:

[How to enable editing of a document in TWebBrowser](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2005/qt/twebbrowseredit.htm)

Using it wasn't as straightforward as one would wish, but I remember doing pretty good things with it.

Comment: Thanks I will try it and let you know